# Serial (COM)-Port reconnect on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

I'm writing a small software connecting to an Arduino or Teensy via Serial. I want the software to realize if the USB-Serial is deconnected and automatically reconnect when its plugged in again.

This is pretty simple under Linux, but I'm not even sure it is possible with Windows, since all the Terminal programs I found can't reconnect to a COM port after it has been disconnected without restarting.

I'm currently using the QT5 QSerialPort implementation, but if someone knows of a C++ class that is able to properly reconnect without restarting the programm, I'd change in a second.

Also if someone knows a serial terminal programm that can automatically reconnect, I'd greatly appreciate an answer.

*edit* I'm using 64-Bit Win7 with usually 32-Bit programs.

Comment: Why would you need to restart the program if you reconnect? I used something similar but with python and i used a thread for fetching data via serial port. It works fine.

Comment: Do you have example code for python? And this did work on Windows right? I don't know why I have to restart, but Putty, hTerm, hyperterm and 3 other tools I tried had to restart as well.

Comment: I posted it as an answer since it has too many characters for a comment.

Comment: The typical USB device driver you get along with the 5 dollar hardware is not up that task, you have to spend real money.  *Always* use the "Remove Hardware Safely" tray icon before you disconnect.

Comment: Why is this a driver problem? Isn't the driver unloaded after I disconnect the device? Or maybe it stays open, because it wasn't properly closed... The python example below proves it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that when the connected device to the serial port gets disconnected, you will receive null in the readline so if it's null, you attempt to reconnect. Also, you need to set a timeout, otherwise readline will just wait forever.
Python example:

```
import serial
import threading
import time
class MainTHread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._data = ""
        self.ser = None
    def run(self):
        while(True):
            try:
                time.sleep(1)
                ser = serial.Serial('COM3',9600,timeout=2)

            except serial.SerialException as err:
                print("Connection failed")
                try:
                    ser.close()
                except UnboundLocalError:
                    print("No Serial")
                print(err)
                continue
            while True:
                try:
                    print("Trying to read")
                    data_json = ser.readline()
                    self._data =data_json.decode('UTF-8');
                    if(not self._data):
                        break
                    print("Main Thread " + self._data)
                except serial.SerialException as err:
                    print("Connection failed")
                    ser.close()
                    break
    def getData(self):
        return self._data
thread = MainTHread()
thread.start()
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it doesn't work for me. When I disconnect the USB/serial port and then plug it in again, it comes up again under the same COM port, but the python script returns "Connection failed" and `err` contains "The system cannot find the file specified." which is the same error I always get. The system is Windows 7 64 Bit, I installed 32bit python & pyserial btw.

Comment: Try to increase the timeout

Comment: The error occurs immediately after the `serial.Serial...` call. I increased the timeout to 10 with no success.

Comment: This is strange. Something like when you reconnect, your device isn;t recognized. Replace this block `except serial.SerialException as err:
                    print("Connection failed")
                    break` with  `except serial.SerialException as err:
                    print("Connection failed")
                    ser.close()
                    break`

Comment: Exactly this solves the problem. You have to make sure to not execute the `ser.close` on the first try, i.e. when you start with the device disconnected.

Comment: On windows 8 it works without closing. I will try to test it in windows 7.

Comment: I defined `ser=None` before the loop and then did `if ser != None and ser.isOpen(): ser.close()`

Answer (score 1):

Easier on Powershell:

```
function triaComPort(){
$selection = [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()

If($selection.Count -gt 0){
    $title = "Serial port selection"
    $message = "Which port would you like to use?"

    # Build the choices menu
    $choices = @()
    For($index = 0; $index -lt $selection.Count; $index++){
        $choices += New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription $selection[$index]
    }

    $options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]$choices
    $result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0) 

    $selection = $selection[$result]
}

return $selection
}

$port = triaComPort

if(!$port){"Must choose";return}

Write-Host $("Port:"+$comport)
$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort $port,57600,None,8,one

while($true){
    if(!$port.IsOpen){
        try{
            $port.Open()
            write-host "+" 
        }catch{
            write-host "-" -NoNewline
        }
    }
    if($port.BytesToRead -gt 0){
        Write-Host $port.ReadExisting()
    }
}
$port.Close()
```

This script prints - when not able to connect and + when connected, the speed is fixed at 57600, you may change it.

Hope it helps.